# How to "pretty-printed" tree object contents with cat-file --batch

Tags: git

I'm trying to "pretty-print" the content of multiple Git objects using `git cat-file --batch` command.

For commit and blob objects, the content is printed as if calling git `cat-file -p <object>`. However, for tree object the content is not "pretty-printed" and the output looks gibberish.

```
# output for commit object looks fine
echo '<commit-object-id>' | git cat-file --batch

# output for tree object is gibberish
echo '<tree-object-id>' | git cat-file --batch
```